# Ko(mu)stache - multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, kohana, mustache, kostache

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($var as $val): ?>
<tr>
<?php foreach($val as $row): ?>
<td> ... </td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

How can I code this with mustache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [KOstache](https://github.com/zombor/KOstache) module, `Kostache::factory()` and assigning your multidimensional array in your controller. Then using an [Implicit iterator](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags) to loop through all elements.